# What are the steps that happen during the build process of ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm new to Azure pipelines and I don't understand the build process for ASP.NET Core 3.1. Like, use nuget, nuget restore, symbols etc. I've had successfully created a pipeline using hosted vs2017 but now with Azure Pipelines as agent pool the jobs I've had created before do not work anymore.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing at the moment? Do you have any error message?

Comment: @HugoBarona it is in nuget restore. 

error : Version 3.1.201 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

Comment: Ok i got it, will give you the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your build pipeline definition, you have the ability to select the host type (VM image) to use while running the jobs.

So in this case I would suggest you to use the latest version of windows as VM image

```
- job: Windows
  pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

More information [in this url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops).